# How can i scroll the panel using Selenium Webdriver

Tags: selenium, scroll, webdriver

I want to move down panel using selenium webdriver.

```
           public void AddCode()

           {

             try
             {
                   getChromeDriver().findElementByClassName("odd").click();
        Thread.sleep(5000);

          getChromeDriver().manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(50, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

                       /*I want to move down panel here.

                         Panel tag : <div id="icd9-tab-data">

                         Scrollbar tag : <div class="mCSB_dragger_bar" style="position: relative; line-height: 505px;"></div>*/

        /* "add-ic9-diagnosis-code" link has been displayed in bottom of panel, so not able to click on this link without scrolling panel. */
        getChromeDriver().findElement(By.id("add-icd9-diagnosis-code")).click();
        Thread.sleep(3000);

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I want to move down panel using selenium webdriver.

Panel tag :

Scrollbar tag :

Answer (score 1):

Do you want something like:

```
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,10);");
```

> //This code is tested to scroll the browser scrollbar

Or you can use this code to focus (move to) the element:

```
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
action.moveToElement(WebElement).perform();
```

If both are not as per your requirement, please elaborate more about your requirement.